# Is there a callback in custom elements for after CSS rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

This is my custom element.

```
class ContextMenu extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.getBoundingClientRect()) // empty
        console.log(this.offsetWidth) // 0
        console.log(this.offsetHeight) // 0

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.getBoundingClientRect()) // good
          console.log(this.offsetWidth) // good
          console.log(this.offsetHeight) // good
        }, 1)
    }
}

document.customElements.define('context-menu', ContextMenu)
```

It is a context menu that appears on right click. My objective here is to immediately check if the context menu is too tall or wide to be shown where the user right-clicked, and if so, I'll adjust it accordingly.

My issue is that `connectedCallback()` seems to run before the element is rendered on the screen. If I set a timer of just 1ms, I'll have the position data that I need.

Is there a native `afterRender()` or anything more appropriate for me to use? My current method is undetectable to the human eye, but relies on CPU power, and extending the timer will make it noticeable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback after the style has been rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895932/callback-after-the-style-has-been-rendered)

Comment: Though this might be a duplicate, please consider the following online resources, that support the accepted answer in the question above: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shadow_tree

Comment: A Custom Element is added to the DOM at the **end** of the ``connectedCallback``. A ``setTimeout`` of 0 is enough to force your JS code to run **after** the current EventLoop has finished.... your element now is **in** the DOM, and you can query DOM related values. So yes, in this scenario where you want to use DOM related values, ``setTimeout`` (or ``requestAnimationFrame`` for that matter) is your only and valid option.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself: it's not logically possible because the inline CSS that positions the context menu is only added later. So in my case the right solution is to listen for "style" attribute changes.

Comment: Maybe it *is* possible if you make the menu itself a custom element?